# light project management software

Tags: macos, tasks, project-management

I'm looking for a simple project management software to help manage my tasks. I'll be using this by myself so I'm not concerned about assigning tasks, etc. I'm on a Macbook Pro, so I can use Mac softwares or install web-based softwares on Localhost (no SaaS), although an OSX app is preferable so I don't have to deal with setting up webserver, DB, etc. Should be free or very very cheap.

The way I want to use it is simple.

1. Open an issue/ticket/project, whatever it's called.
2. Update the ticket with new actions done, or pending actions.
3. Attach any files associated with it.
4. Export as Excel per project if needed.

The way I see this it's kinda like a bug-tracking or ticketing systems used by Support departments, but I'm not sure if I want to use those since they are specialized for software.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Bug-tracking software (or more generally, issue tracking) is usually quite configurable. Have you looked e.g. at Atlassian Jira?

Comment: Lighthouse might also be possible, there's even a Mac client called Lighthouse Keeper. As a comment, since I have no experience in using it.

Comment: Isn't Jira rather expensive?

Comment: If you consider that a desktop based (single/few user) system works for you, I'd have thought the 5$ license for 5 users or what they offer might be a possibility. You didn't mention multi-user reqs.

Comment: No no I will be using this by myself, single user. I didn't see $5 option though. I saw many within the hundreds and thousands range?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, 10$ for 10 users. Still.

Comment: People donate more than that to some [open source] projects that they hardly ever use.  A $10 price tag, even if for a single user, seems quite reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not looking for the right tool. You should ask for an issue tracking software or at least a task management software. Project management is too much for your needs. You could try [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I tried one a long time ago called OpenProj because one of my clients was interested, and they used it for a while.  It's fairly similar to Microsoft Project:

OpenProj (free and open source)
  http://www.openproj.org/openproj/

You'll probably have to try it to determine if it meets your needs.  If you do, please do post a comment back here to indicate whether it worked out okay for you.

Comment: I don't think that's what I want. I don't see a way to update tasks with actions related to it.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  It's good to know that OpenProj doesn't have that feature.